# Truncate snowflake table before loading data from a snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and doing a POC following [Automating Snowpipe for Amazon S3](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html) document.

Here is the snowpipe I've created

```
create pipe demo_db.public.storage_to_snowflake_pipe 
auto_ingest=true as copy into demo_db.public.test_table(Name) from (Select $1 FROM @demo_db.public.stage_table)file_format = (type = 'CSV' skip_header = 1);
```

Is there any possibility to truncate/delete data in the snowflake table (test_table) before snowpipe loads data in to it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked this with Snowflake. This is not supported with snowpipe yet

Answer (score 1):

Since you are truncating the table I assume it's a staging table and you will have another process to read data from it and move to another table.

If that's the case you can use `ALTER TABLE .. SWAP WITH ...` to achieve your goal.

Assuming your table is `T_STAGE` and it's being loaded by Snowpipe, you can create a secondary stage table `T_STAGE_INC` with the same structure

[SWAP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html#alter-table) will swap the data between the tables.

At the beginning of your process that reads data from `T_STAGE` you need to run

```
ALTER TABLE T_STAGE SWAP WITH T_STAGE_INC
```

and use `T_STAGE_INC` as your source.

After your process is done you can truncate `T_STAGE_INC` table.

It also needs to be empty for the first run

Comment: Apologies. I have updated my question with snowpipe details. It's the destination table I have to truncate and load.